# telegram CallBack Query returns null update in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, telegram-bot

I have a confusing bug  don't know how to solve it.
I'm developing a telegram bot.
I Used Inline Keyboards for some messages which sends to a channel which bot has administrator role in it.
But the problem is the callback query from inline keyboard.
It returns null in `update.CallbackQuery`
Here is my inline keyboard:

```
var sendBid = new InlineKeyboardButton();
sendBid.Text = "Send Bids";
sendBid.CallbackData = "SendBid";

var showBids = new InlineKeyboardButton();
showBids.Text = "Show Bids";
showBids.CallbackData = "ShowBids";


InlineKeyboardMarkup inline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
{
   new []
     {
       sendBid,showBids
     }
});
```

And when I want to get it from `Update update` frome the code below:

```
public int Index(Update update)
 {
   if (update.CallbackQuery!=null)
   {
      //some code is here...
   }
 }
```

the update is null.
I get messages of `ReplyMarkupKeyboard` from this Update but no any reply of `inlineKeyboards`
Please Help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this problem, Check `allowedTypes` argument in `StartRecieving` method, you must pass `UpdateType.CallbackQuery`, I also suggest you to use `OnCallbackQuery` Event